# Chrome updates fail with error when updating repository information

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, updates, google-chrome

When running `sudo apt-get update` I get the error:

> Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release Unable to find expected entry ‘main/binary-i386/Packages’ in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

But this used to work until a few days ago. The mentioned web address `dl.google.com/.../stable/Release` actually exists but it contains only `Architectures: amd64`. The error message mentions `binary-i386`, which is not amd64.

I tried all the usual fixes for general "Failed to fetch" problems but it did not make any difference in this case. Any suggestions? How can I fix the error message?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because Google has stopped support for 32-bit version of chrome or chromium.

Please edit `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list`, replace the line

```
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

By

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

You should also check other sources list under `/etc/apt`, especially `/etc/apt/sources.list`, 
remove any line including `http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/`. 
The following command would help you find out such files.

```
grep "http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/" -r /etc/apt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the instructions here:

https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/48oje6/linux_how_to_fix_failed_to_fetch/

Worked for me

Comment: Good practice is to add some info to your post, so it will remain valuable if the link will be broken.